# Plasma.io: What if someone is offline during a mass withdrawal?

Tags: blockchain, proof-of-stake, attacks, plasma

I'm reading the Plasma paper published a couple months ago, and on page 27, they talk about "Adversarial Mass Withdrawals" in the event of block withholding.

My question is, what if someone is offline during a mass withdrawal? The paper says in the event of block withholding "one simply should exit from this Plasma chain to another as quickly as possible." There's a fairly long process to do a mass withdrawal, but if someone is offline, I'm guessing they can't participate in time, so how is this problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually asked Vitalik about this during a talk, he said the process for a mass withdrawal should last a long time, for example 2 weeks, so you just need to be online within that time. He didn't say what the consequence is if you're not online during those (example) 2 weeks, so I assume you just loose your funds.